# How show text box on button click in colab notebook?

Tags: user-interface, google-colaboratory

i know how to display a text box, and how to display a button. But I need to show text box on a button click in colab notebook. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply enter the URL in the {YOUR_URL} portion of the code below and copy it to the text cell of the ipynb file.

```markdown
<a href="YOUR_URL" target="_parent"><img src="https://colab.research.google.com/assets/colab-badge.svg" alt="Open in Colab"/></a>
```